# Adhoc record comparison oracle

Tags: oracle

So I have some records in excel with 4 pieces of information:

Date, Location, Workstation, Trans_ID.

I need to check these records against an oracle database. If this were sql server, I could just create a temp table & insert them, then join off the temp table and the table I need to check.

Anyone have a good solution for oracle?

Comment: Why can't you create a table in Oracle, use it for your check and then, if you don't need it, drop it?

Comment: One thing I would use (and I use it often) would be external tables. They allow you to query directly the file. https://community.oracle.com/blogs/renato.pedroso/2015/08

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I load spreadsheet data into Oracle regularly with TOAD [and even SQL*Loader].  I'm sure you can find some tools to help you with this.